# text alignment in plot R

Tags: r, text, plot, expression

I am adding text to a plot in R but right now the alignment of the last part of the text is off.  I am trying to align the R2 part of the text under the two blahs.  This is just an example.

Example

```
plot(1:10)
text(8,4,expression("blah \nblah\n"~R^2~"= 0.98"),col="red")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `expression` only in the expression used, and use the `adj` parameter to adjust alignment.

```
plot(1:10)
text(8,4,c("blah \nblah\n", expression(paste(R^2, "= 0.98"))),col="red", adj = 0)
```

Additionaly, it seem like you're trying to do some legend. You could use `legend` to do it:

```
legend('bottomright', c('blah', 'blah', expression(paste(R^2, "= 0.98"))))
```

This would be more readable code, and you can adjust settings according to your needs. Check `?legend` for more information.